# How can I get/inject the test bean form context with using Spring Test?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-test

I use SpringJUnit4ClassRunner for testing application, but I can not inject own test instance into other class instances. The reason of injecting class is that I need to prepare test class for testing.
How can I get/inject the test bean into rules/other classes form context in the Spring test?

Example :

Test class 1:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { AppTestConfig.class })
public class TestOne {

    @Autoware
    @Rule
    public SimpleClassRule simpleClassRule;

    @Test
    public void test(){
        //do something
    }

}
```

Test class 2:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { AppTestConfig.class })
public class TestTwo {

    @Autoware
    @Rule
    public SimpleClassRule simpleClassRule;

    @Test
    public void test(){
        //do something
    }

}
```

Rule:

```
public SimpleClassRule extend ExternalResource {

    @Autoware
    ??? // need to have test class or TestClass.getClass() ???

    @Override
    protected void before() throws Throwable {
        // need to have test class or TestClass.getClass() ???
    }
}
```

Comment: I found the following solution to use the Sprint test TestExecutionListener-s with @TestExecutionListeners annotation.